# Is the Base chain network not supported by the SafeAuthPack yet?

Tags: safe-core-sdk, safe-core

I just saw that the smart contracts of the `v1.4.1` support the Base Goerli Testnet. And wanted to test the Core AA SDK to integrate it into a Base network app, however

> Supported networks:
> Production: Ethereum, Polygon, BSC, Avalanche, Optimism, Celo, Arbitrum, Gnosis chain
> Test: Goerli, Sepolia, Polygon Mumbai, BSC Testnet, Avalanche Testnet, Arbitrum Testnet, Optimism Testnet

based on the quote above it seems like the Base network is not yet supported by the SafeAuth.

Is the are another ways to use Safe wallet to do the following:

create an address with AA, and call a smart contract on the Base chain?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, as of now, Base is not supported by SafeAuth. You could try deploying and interacting directly with the contracts on Base, without using the SDK.

Hope it helps, Louis